# Export list of folders from shared drives on network

Tags: powershell

Hopefully this is a quick and easy process.

I need to build a tree (using powershell) of our network folders for auditing perposes.

I am wanting to start at the top level, root folder and encompass everything that falls under it.  I know it will take a long time but that is okay with me.

I have full permissions on the root drive and inherency is turned on so there should be no folder permission errors.

I would like to export the tree to a .csv to look like this

Folder Name                             Folder Path
Folder1                                \root\path\folder1
Folder2                                \root\path\folder2

Here is what I have so far:

```
$path = "root\path\folder"
$reportPath = "C:\scripts

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Directory | Select-object psPath,psChildName | Export-CSV -path $reportPath
```

This gives me the results I am looking for but I get the dreaded "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::" in the PSPath.

Does anyone know what I need to add in to hide that precursor to the pathway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FullName` is probably the property you're after. And if you want to have the CSV properties say "Folder Name" and "Folder Path" you can either use calculated properties with `Select-Object` or create your own object in a foreach-object loop.

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Directory |
    Select-object @{n='Folder Name';e='Name'},@{n='Folder Path';e='FullName'} |
        Export-Csv -path $reportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Folder Name' = $_.Name
        'Folder Path' = $_.FullName
    }
} | Export-Csv -path $reportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You are a genius among men.  Solved it immediately!  Thank you kindly!

Comment: When the script finally finished, I did notice a couple of errors.  One was an access denied error which is not a big deal but the other is a "Could not find a part of the path" error which I am assuming is related to the length of the path.  Is there a way that I could easily export those errors to the same sheet as well by adding a third column?